# Formik Field Array for Nested fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I want to render a Form with nested fields inside a `<FieldArray />` component. But when I create the Form Fields based on the index, I get extra fields that I don't want. As shown below:

[image: friends_list]

As you can see Julia and 28 should be on the same row. But instead, I get four fields in two rows. Empty fields are also writing the age and name values when typed. I don't get why this is happening. But I don't want them. Below you can see the code for the component. I also created a sandbox to work on it in here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/formik-nested-array-field-problem-bbqtq).

Note: I want these nested Fields so the structure of my array `friends: [{ name: "Julia" }, { age: "28" }]` is important to the question.

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray } from "formik";

// Here is an example of a form with an editable list.
// Next to each input are buttons for insert and remove.
// If the list is empty, there is a button to add an item.
const FriendList = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Friend List</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ friends: [{ name: "Julia" }, { age: "28" }] }}
      onSubmit={values =>
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500)
      }
      render={({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray
            name="friends"
            render={arrayHelpers => (
              <div>
                {values.friends.map((friend, index) => (
                  <div key={index}>
                    <Field name={`friends[${index}].name`} />
                    <Field name={`friends.${index}.age`} />
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                    >
                      -
                    </button>
                  </div>
                ))}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({ name: "", age: "" })}
                >
                  +
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          />
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}</pre>
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);

export default FriendList;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong initial values, should be like:

```
[{ name: "Julia", age: "27" }]
```

Instead you passed 2 array items

Comment: no, I want these nested fields for another purpose.

Comment: thank you but I need to create a JS object so much more complex than this simple example provided here. hence this is unfortunately not answering my question.

Comment: you can transform your array before put it into formik and after submit - transform it again to the structure that you want

Comment: `friends: [{ name: "Julia" }, { age: "28" }]` doesn't make sense as a data structure. `friends` should be an array of `friend` objects, and those objects would have `name` and age properties which is what Satif has shown you in their answer. If you want to change the structure of the array to something else for another purpose then there are lots of [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to help you out.